# AirPods: listen to audio + record video + use microphones?

Tags: video, music, airpods

I'm trying to record some sing-along videos that will later be merged.  This is for a school musical during quarantine, and we will be making a lot of these clips, so a good capture process would really help.

It would be super slick if I could do all of the following at the same time:

1. Use AirPods with an iPhone or Mac.
2. Listen to a song through the AirPods.  (I can arrange to stream it in almost any imaginable way.)
3. Record a video.
4. Use the AirPods' microphone(s) as the (only!) audio source for the video.

Many thanks in advance if anyone knows a recipe.  I'm happy to buy an app if that will do it.

Plan B is to use the iPhone and AirPods only for listening, and use a separate camera.  But I don't have a separate camera that has a good microphone, so I'd have to live with the lousy audio, or buy new camera & mic hardware, maybe a vidcast setup.

Answer (score 1):

I believe as long as your AirPods are connected they will be used as the default microphone input, so any video recording software will work fine.

For example, in QuickTime Player, go to File > New Movie Recording. Then click on the arrow next to the record button and you can select exactly which microphone and video inputs to use if it's not already default.

Comment: Yea I just tested QuickTime and it worked beautifully! Only issue may be if the Mac doesn’t have a built in camera and OP can’t connect their camera to their Mac. I have some other ideas if that’s the case, but this is gonna be the simplest.

Comment: This almost works.  But as soon as I start a recording, any other playback is stopped.  So I get 1, 3, and 4, but not 2.